# Description of how the variance in `Y` changes with the discrete variable `X`?

Tags: anova, variance, nonparametric, f-test

Let `Y` be a continuous response variable and `X` be a discrete explanatory variable. I am interested in developing a statistical model to analyze how the within group variance in `Y` varies in response to `X`.

I could do a F-test in order to test if two groups have equal or unequal variance. However, I have more than two groups and I am willing to get a description of how a change in `X` yield to a change in the variance in `Y`. For example, I would like to be able to compare using AIC or BIC linear and quadratic regressions to tell how variance in `Y` changes with `X`.

I was thinking about eventually resampling my groups independently in order to draw the sampling distribution of within-group variance and use these sample variances data points to run a standard anova on them but sounds like a weird solution.

**How should I analyze how the within group variance in `Y` changes with the discrete variable `X`?** A simple example would be very welcome!

Comment: This sounds like an exploratory exercise rather than a confirmatory one. Why not, then, start simply by measuring the variances of $Y$ and comparing them to $X$, perhaps with a scatterplot?

Comment: Yes, I did that. `Variance(Y)` looks like an increasing function of `X` and eventually reaches a horizontal asymptote at large `X`. But I don't know how much sampling error I have in my estimates. I could eventually calculate it "by hand" and then look how well different functions seem to fit the data. I would love if there was to exist a specific methodology and test to estimate the parameters of the function that fit the data and test whether it really is different from the function $Var(Y) = mean(Var(Y))$.